# How do I push specific files from Azure DevOps Server to a Github?

Tags: git, github, tfs, tfvc, azure-devops-server-2019

I have a rather large TFVC project that I have no interest in migrating to git,  but I do want to push releases to Github as part of my build pipeline.  At the tail end of my pipeline I have 3 ZIP files and I'd like to either commit them to the repo on Github and/or publish them as a Release on Github.

It doesn't matter what my original project uses for source control because the files are being packaged by several intermediary steps and thus the source of the push to Github is a temp folder on the local disk;  I can copy them as needed (but prefer not to,  they're huge).

I've tried the "Github release" task,  but it never actually triggers -- even though I put a '*' in the Source Tag filter,  it never actually applies and always says `Release will not be created as the tags for the target commit do not match with the given tag pattern`.  It looks like the "tags" it's seeing is simply the Changeset ID (which is fine because I have the filter set to '*',  it just fails to match).

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm aware of the Github API but I feel like this is a common task and I can't imagine that everyone that's not using git natively is manually uploading their releases to Github via the web or writing custom scripts to do it.   Also I would prefer not to pull down the entire repo to the server just to update these 3 files,  this is a large game project.

Comment: It's probably not a common task for TFVC to GitHub; TFVC is more or less an afterthought at this point. The industry has moved past centralized version control. The GitHub release task is assuming the source repo is Git, and it's not going to work against TFVC.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Daniel, the [GitHub Release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/github-release?view=azure-devops) is assuming the source repo is Git and its `Target` argument is *the commit SHA for which the GitHub release will be created*, so TFVC repository is not supported for this task.

As a workaround, I am afraid that you will have to checkout remote GitHub repository using below command:
`git clone https://username:password@github.com/myrepository/repositoryname.git`

And then copy or move the target ZIP files to the local repository workspace, then make a commit to push these files to GitHub repository.